# Bitwise operation on char pointer

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Could somebody please help me to understand  the purpose of operations in this code:

```
struct mystruct {
    char c;
    long int i32;
    int i16;
} s;
unsigned char *p = buf;
fread(buf, 7, 1, fp);
s.c = *p++;

    s.i32 = (long)*p++ << 24;
    s.i32 |= (long)*p++ << 16;
    s.i32 |= (unsigned)(*p++ << 8);
    s.i32 |= *p++;

    s.i16 = *p++ << 8;
    s.i16 |= *p++;
```

Basically it seems to try to unpack the variables using the char pointer. But I did not understand the code  related to the `long int`, and in particular the following:

```
s.i32 = (long)*p++ << 24;
    s.i32 |= (long)*p++ << 16;
    s.i32 |= (unsigned)(*p++ << 8);
    s.i32 |= *p++;
```

Comment: Join us in the new millenium and `#include <cstdint>` and use `int32_t` or `int_least32_t`.

Comment: This is confusing. You're saying you wrote this code, but you want someone else to explain how it works? Or, is this an example from your C++ textbook chapter on bitwise operators, and something is unclear to you in the textbook's explanation of its example program? Can you quote a brief excerpt, from your textbook, that's unclear to you?

Comment: There are no bitwise operations on the pointer. Only the things it points to.

Answer (score 2):

The code reads a 32bit signed integer in big endian format and converts it into the machine format by shifting each byte to the position it belongs.

The code also assumes CHAR_BITS == 8 but that's reasonable for most archs.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/byteswap for how to do this better in the future.

Under POSIX you can use `ntohl` from `<arpa/inet.h>`.

Comment: (long)*p++ <<24 , would point to memory after shifting 24 bits from the current position
 ,  could it just not be (long)*p << 24

Comment: That's `((long) (*p)) << 24; p = p + 1;` **post** increment and it only reads 8bits, not 24.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down

```
*p++ // read a byte pointed to by a pointer and increment the pointer

(long)*p++ // cast that byte to a long

(long)*p++ << 24 // shift the bits of the long left (up) by 24 bits

s.i32 = (long)*p++ << 24; // assign the shifted bits to s.i32
```

So the whole process has taken one byte and placed it in bits 24 to 31 (the highest 8 bits) of a 32 bit integer.

Next step

```
*p++ // read a byte pointed to by a pointer and increment the pointer

(long)*p++ // cast that byte to a long

(long)*p++ << 16 // shift the bits of the long left (up) by 16 bits

s.i32 |= (long)*p++ << 16; // combine the shifted bits with the existing contents of s.i32
```

So this step has read another byte and placed it in bit 16 to 23 of a 32 bit integer. So we have now read bits 16 to 31 of the 32 bit integer.

I'm sure you can work out the rest for yourself. Basically it just completes bits 0 to 15 of the 32 bit integer.